# ThirdPersonController collision not calling OnTriggerEnter event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Test")
        {
            this.transform.position = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a ThirdPersonController and i want it to collide with a cube or cylinder.
The script is attached to the ThirdPersonController.

I tried to add either to the cylinder or the cube Rigidbody turned on/off the Use Gravity and the Is Kinematic but nothing. It's not getting to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThirdPersonController` uses [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) and [`OnControllerColliderHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html) is used for that not `OnTriggerEnter`.

Note that you must move it with the [`Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) function not directly by its transform in order for `OnControllerColliderHit` to be called.

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is correct but the thing wrong here is you are changing the position of the object which is colliding with a second object , but the thing id the thing is the collider is already there.....
As it's alternative try to print any statement when collision happens like this

```
private  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
  if (other.tag==your_tag)

{
print("message");
}
}
```